# make auto install app in android easier?

Tags: android

I have android app, and I want to make it auto update, so user don't have to do anything.

I already know how to automatically check versionCode and compare it with this [answer about Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically/11856143#11856143) But I still have to install it manually:

[image]

Is there any way to make it easier for user? for example **install it in background** or make it **can't open unless it's already install**?

I use this app for company use, so I need to force them to update.

Comment: You need to have root access to install apk in the background

Comment: So I need to rooting every device? Can I do that using my app?

Comment: No you cannot root device just like that. Different device have different procedure. Do a quick Google about rooting android device.